# ¿Para que sirve un Symbol en JavaScript? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Leyendo la documentación de MDN donde se habla sobre el dato primitivo `Symbol` por más que leo y vuelvo a leer no entiendo cuál sería un caso de uso para dicho elemento más que para iterar `Symbol.iterator`.

La documentación dice que su uso es con propósitos de *debug*, pero aún con ello no entiendo para que usar un `Symbol` para debuguear si existe `console.log()` o `debugger`.

Entiendo que es un dato primitivo y por consiguiente, inmutable. En los ejemplos he visto que hacen algo como lo siguiente:

```
var sym = Symbol('Llave'),
    obj = {
        [sym]: 'valor'
    };

console.log(obj[sym]); // valor
console.log(obj['Llave']); // undefined
```

¿Por qué usar un `Symbol`? si se puede usar un llave tradicional (llave: valor).

Fuentes:

- [Symbol - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)
- [lukehoban/es6features · GitHub](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#symbols)
- [ECMAScript 6 — New Features: Overview & Comparison](http://es6-features.org/#SymbolType)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Los Symbols son tipo de dato único que es inmutable y puede ser utilizado como identificador de propiedades de objeto. Estos son como los tipos `Number`, `String`, y `Boolean` primitivos.

Para crearlo se hace de la siguiente forma, sin usar la palabra new, ya que los `Symbols` tienen una función `Symbol` la cual es utilizada para crearlos;

```
var sym1 = Symbol();
var sym2 = Symbol("foo");
var sym3 = Symbol("foo");
```

Como comente arriba al ser tipos únicos, el creara un nuevo Symbol el cual no sera a otro:

```
Symbol("foo") === Symbol("foo"); // false
```

Acerca del `debuging` Estos son considerados poderosos, ya que poseen una descripcion, cual es usada solo para debug para hacernos la vida mas facil al hacer debug por consola:

```
console.log(Symbol('foo')); // prints "Symbol(foo)" to the console.  
assert(Symbol('foo').toString() === 'Symbol(foo)');
```

¿Para que son buenos?:

1. Para crear y almacenar valores como `integer` y `string` que no van cambiar.
2. Se puede utilizar para guardar custom metadata de lo objetos, que son como secundarias para el objeto actual.

Conclusión:

Son unas pequeñas constantes que tienen algunas propiedades extras, que nos permiten trabajar mejor en debug y guardar valores únicos.

Un buen recurso es esta [pagina](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/) donde hay ejemplo, y explican mucho mas extenso lo que son los symbols.

Comment: Entiendo que son primitivos e inmutables, pero en realidad ¿por qué usarlos? es decir, en la MDN mencionan algo como lo siguiente: `var sym = Symbol('key'); var obj = { [sym]: 'value' }; obj[ sym ];`. ¿Por qué usar un `Symbol` en lugar de una llave común?.

Comment: +1 Para crear y almacenar valores como integer y string que no van cambiar.

Comment: @Chofoteddy Porque permiten guardar valores que no van a cambiar y adicionalemnte, si son únicos se da mejor utilidad, solo por eso, ya que en ES5 no podías hacer eso. en cambio si creas un Objeto tienes una alta probabilidad de duplicar valores

Comment: Su uso "oficial" es definir "propiedades especiales" como `Symbol.iterator`, cualquier otro uso es, en mi opinión, abusar del tipo.

Comment: Sacando datos de Wikipedia

Answer (score 7):

Ya que @WilfredoP no ha mencionado los símbolos globales voy a aprovechar:

```
var s1 = Symbol.for('foo');
var s2 = Symbol.for('foo');
s1 === s2 // retorna true, ya que Symbol.for(<name>) genera símbolos globales.
```

Aquí, `s1` y `s2` son básicamente el mismo símbolo. Pero como se codea un símbolo no es tan importante como su propósito:

Los `Symbols` son parte de un movimiento que esta haciendo Javascript hacia la [metaprogramacion](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramaci%C3%B3n). Y no están solos en esto, ECMAScript 2015 incluye otras 2 incorporaciones que apuntan en esa linea que son [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) y [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect).

Por ello, su uso es muy variado. La cuestión pasa por qué semántica tendrán estos para tu aplicación.

### Hay algunos símbolos bien conocidos!

#### Symbol.hasInstance: instanceof

`Symbol.hasInstance` es el símbolo que controla el comportamiento de `instanceof`. Es decir `A instanceof B` es equivalente `B[Symbol.hasInstance](A)`.

Ejemplo:

```
class MiArray {  
    // aquí sobrecargo el operador instanceof 
    static [Symbol.hasInstance](otro) {
        return Array.isArray(otro);
    }
}
assert([] instanceof MiArray); // pasa, por evaluarse como true
```

#### Symbol.iterator

Sobercargar el metodo `objeto[Symbol.iterator]` permite cambiar el comportamiento del operador `of` en un bloque `for .. of` si se sobrecarga como función generadora.

Ejemplo:

```
class IterarSaltando {  
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    var i = 0;
    while(this[i] !== undefined) {
      yield this[i];
      i+=2;
    }
  }
}
var iterarSaltando = new IterarSaltando();
iterarSaltando[0] = '1';
iterarSaltando[1] = '2';
iterarSaltando[2] = '3';
for(var value of iterarSaltando) {  
    console.log(value); // 1, luego 3
}
```

Hay una [lista](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) bastante larga de estos símbolos pre-definidos por el estándar. Pero no todos están 100% implementados en todos los navegadores.

Comment: ¿Sería una equivalencia a un Symbol singleton? (por así llamarlo).

Comment: si te sirve, pienso que es una comparación valida. Yo prefiero entenderlos comos son. Son símbolos globales a todo el ambiente de ejecución.

Comment: Actúan como sobrecarga de operadores :D ¡eso está de lujo!. Hacía falta algo así desde hace tiempo.